# How to save changes from json in the same column or in a new one?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to know what I can add to the code so that it saves the jsons in the same column or in a new one but with the changes that I am making through the conditionals (something like overwriting it with the changes included). I am not that skilled in python but I am learning, if you can help me I would really appreciate it.

```
for i in xs2['input_parameters2']:
    datos = json.loads(i)
    #new = []
    #print(datos['minuta_id'])
    for companias in datos['companies']:
        if 'financial_accounts' in 'companies':
            for dict1 in range(len(xs2)):
                if companias['ruc'] == xs2.loc[dict,'RUC']:
                    #companias['financial_accounts'].update(xs2.loc[dict,'dic'])
                    companias['financial_accounts'] =[
                        {"code":371,"name":"Inversiones en valores","value":xs2.loc[dict,'INVERSIONES_EN_VALORES']},
                        {"code":408,"name":"Capital","value":xs2.loc[dict,'CAPITAL_FIJO']},
                        {"code":414,"name":"Resultados acumulados","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_ACUMULADOS']},
                        {"code":415,"name":"Resultado del ejercicio","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_DEL_EJERCICIO']},
                        {"code":416,"name":"Ventas","value":xs2.loc[dict,'VENTAS_NETAS']}]
                    print(companias['financial_accounts'])
                    print(companias['ruc'])      
                    
        else:
            for dict in range(len(xs2)):
                if companias['ruc'] == xs2.loc[dict,'RUC']:
                    companias['financial_accounts'] =[
                        {"code":371,"name":"Inversiones en valores","value":xs2.loc[dict,'INVERSIONES_EN_VALORES']},
                        {"code":408,"name":"Capital","value":xs2.loc[dict,'CAPITAL_FIJO']},
                        {"code":414,"name":"Resultados acumulados","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_ACUMULADOS']},
                        {"code":415,"name":"Resultado del ejercicio","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_DEL_EJERCICIO']},
                        {"code":416,"name":"Ventas","value":xs2.loc[dict,'VENTAS_NETAS']}]
                    #print(new)
```

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's a standard built-in function/type

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? It looks like it's putting the changes in the `financial_accounts` column.

Comment: What's the difference between the code in the `if` and `else`?

Comment: the difference between the if and the else, is that in the first one I want to replace the values of "financial_accounts" by the new ones that I am indicating and in the second one I want that key to be created as new because inside the json it would not find "financial_accounts". Now, what I finally want to do is that these changes that I am making are saved in the same column from where it is obtaining the information or it would also be useful if I can create another column with the modified json.

Comment: There's no difference between replacing a dictionary element and creating a new dicitonary element with the same name. They're both just an assignment to the element.

Comment: But in that case how should I do it taking into consideration what I said? if in the first case of getting "financial_accounts" I want it to replace the values and in the next one to create the complete key of "financial_accounts" with the values

Comment: Just get rid of the `if` since both `if` and `else` do the same thing.

Comment: You can also break out of the `for dict` loop once you find the matching `companias['ruc']`

Comment: but if I remove the "else" and leave only the "if" it only makes the change of values when it gets the key "financial_accounts" but now I do not know how to do to indicate to it that in the cases that it does not get it it must create it new with the values that I will give it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `if 'financial_accounts' in 'companies':` statement, since you're doing the same thing in both `if` and `else`. Just do that unconditionally.

```
for i in xs2['input_parameters2']:
    datos = json.loads(i)
    #new = []
    #print(datos['minuta_id'])
    for companias in datos['companies']:
        for dict1 in range(len(xs2)):
            if companias['ruc'] == xs2.loc[dict,'RUC']:
                #companias['financial_accounts'].update(xs2.loc[dict,'dic'])
                companias['financial_accounts'] =[
                    {"code":371,"name":"Inversiones en valores","value":xs2.loc[dict,'INVERSIONES_EN_VALORES']},
                    {"code":408,"name":"Capital","value":xs2.loc[dict,'CAPITAL_FIJO']},
                    {"code":414,"name":"Resultados acumulados","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_ACUMULADOS']},
                    {"code":415,"name":"Resultado del ejercicio","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_DEL_EJERCICIO']},
                    {"code":416,"name":"Ventas","value":xs2.loc[dict,'VENTAS_NETAS']}]
                print(companias['financial_accounts'])
                print(companias['ruc'])      
                break
```

There's no need to test whether `financial_accounts` is already in the dictionary. The assignment will replace it if it already exists, otherwise it will create it.

You would only need that kind of test if you wanted to combine the new value with the old value. But since you're replacing it, the old value doesn't matter.

Comment: thank you very much my friend I used your guide. I wanted to ask you if now I want to save the json with the change I made how should I do, I need to create an object where I can save the same information but now with the additions made.

Comment: You can append `datos` to a list to save all the update objects.